# Anchor menu different css at the active menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a one page website with 1 always at top menu with anchor links. I'd like to change the color of the menu when its active. I don't know how could I get which menu is active at which anchor link I passed or something.

Here's what I have:

```html
<div id="menu" class="default">
    <img align="left" width="8%" height="100%"src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/pics/a.jpeg"/>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#menu1">menu1</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive" href="#menu2">menu2</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive"  href="#menu3">menu3</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive"  href="#menu4">menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div><!-- close menu -->
```

```css
#inactive {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
#active {
    color: #deb48f;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The color is changed. I need a javascript that changes the class of these menus based on which one is on the screen now.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code in javascript? Even if it's broken, so we can help you from there. You will need to use the magic of the internet to do a bit of research to find out how others have done it so if you finally you get stuck on a particular issue come back and we’ll try to help you with it. Good luck!

Comment: # is for selecting ID's. to select class, use .active and .inactive

Comment: I'm re-reading the questions and I'm not sure what you mean by "change the color when it is active". Do you mean you want to change the color when the mouse is being clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to use bootstrap with the scrollspy plugin, if you're willing to add bootstrap to your website. 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Also, as a side note, I would remove the need for an inactive class by adding an id="tabs" to the nav tag and changing the css to

```
#tabs a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
#tabs a.active{
    color: #deb48f;
}
```

Note that the # denotes the id of a tag, and a period is used to denote the css of a tag.

This my first ever post on StackOverflow, so I hope I did this right and that this helped!

Edit: 
Here's some jQuery you can add after your div so that you'll at least be able to change the colors of the tabs when you click on them:

```
<script>
    $('li > a').click(function() {
        $('li > a').removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the inactive class from the HTML and rename the CSS block to `nav ul li a` instead of `.class`. Then use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Here is the modified HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="default">
    <img align="left" width="8%" height="100%"src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/pics/a.jpeg"/>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#menu1">menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu2">menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu3">menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu4">menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div><!-- close menu -->
```

And the CSS:

```
nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
.active {
    color: #deb48f;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not static html function, so you must use javascript *(simplicity jQuery)* for this magic.

Next to do:
1: it must be determined witch the event triggers the happend
2: how it will change the color

First is the click event on  element which is trigger the action.
This is in jQuery: `$(selector).on('click', function() { *function body* });`

Second, you must define only the .active class with background-color:

```
.active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

And when you clicked the navigation element, remove .active class from all element, and add for only the clicked.

function body =

```
$allmenulink = $('#mynav a'); 
$allmenulink.removeClass('active'); 
$this = $(this)
$this.addClass('active');
```

Here is full example:

```js
// click event on a element in mynav
$('#mynav a').on('click', function() {
  // select all menu link element
  $allmenulink = $('#mynav a');
  // remove .active class from all menu element
  $allmenulink.removeClass('active');
  // clicked element
  $this = $(this)
    // add .active class for clicked element
  $this.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
li>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* set background for menu item with active class */

li>a.active {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mynav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#menu1">menu1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="" href="#menu2">menu2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="" href="#menu3">menu3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="" href="#menu4">menu4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```